# How to add an image property to an entity?

Tags: entities

I have a requirement to add a unique icon to each bundle of an entity. My entity code is very similar to the [model](https://www.drupal.org/project/model) module. I have 2 entities, one for holding the actual entity instances, another for holding the type information.

Each entity type will have a unique icon which will be shown while adding that entity in the creation form. For this, I need to add a custom property to the entity which will hold the image file data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an integer property that references the `fid` column in the `file_managed` table.

For inspiration, check out the [`user_account_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_account_form/7) function (the `picture` element) and associated validate/submit handlers. They show the exact methodology you need to use.